How to configure spring-boot logback rollingpolicy
How do I set up application.yml for logging by day + hour? That is, I need the logs to be saved in a separate file every hour and stored in folders by day, with a storage depth of 7 days. As a result, there should be 7 folders with a date in each of which 24 log files are stored.
My current application.yaml:
    logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
  file:
    name: "pathToLogs/myApp/logs/myApp.log"
    max-history: 7
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      file-name-pattern: "pathToLogs/myApp/logs/logs/myApp_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.gz"


logging:
  file:
    name: "./logs/app.log"
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      file-name-pattern: "./logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd, aux}/app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.gz"
      max-history: 168

24 hours in every date folders * 7 days = 168 files
